# Issue changing JPanel with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm having a problem! I'm making an app with multiple panels. I'm using Card Layout and I don't have this problem with changing to the other panels. I have a JButton (in a panel called optionsPanel) that should first change to the panel "panelCargando" (which has two JLabel, one with text and the other with a squared animated GIF (72x72)) and then looks after some info using Twitter4J that is showed in another JPanel called tweetsPanel. The problem is that when I press the button, it doesn't hide the other panels and make "panelCargando" visible, it keeps the options panel in the front and when it finishes looking for the info, it puts both panels together. Here's the code that I'm using in the ActionListener of the JButton:

```
btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            mainPanel.setVisible(false);
            optionsPanel.setVisible(false);
            tweetsPanel.setVisible(false);
            panelCargando.setVisible(true);

            long lCursor = -1;
            IDs friendsIDs;
            try
            {
                friendsIDs = twitter.getFriendsIDs(twitter.getId(), lCursor);
                System.out.println(twitter.showUser(twitter.getId()).getName());
                do
                {
                  for (long i : friendsIDs.getIDs())
                  {
                      if(textArea.getText().isEmpty())
                      {
                          textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "ID de usuario: " + i +
                          "\nNombre de usuario: @" + twitter.showUser(i).getScreenName() + 
                          "\nNombre: " + twitter.showUser(i).getName() +
                          "\nDescripción: " + twitter.showUser(i).getDescription() +
                          "\nImagen de perfil: " + twitter.showUser(i).getProfileImageURLHttps() +
                          "\nSigue a " + twitter.showUser(i).getFriendsCount() + " usuarios" + 
                          "\nTiene " + twitter.showUser(i).getFollowersCount() + " seguidores\n");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\nID de usuario: " + i +
                          "\nNombre de usuario: @" + twitter.showUser(i).getScreenName() + 
                          "\nNombre: " + twitter.showUser(i).getName() +
                          "\nDescripción: " + twitter.showUser(i).getDescription() +
                          "\nImagen de perfil: " + twitter.showUser(i).getProfileImageURLHttps() +
                          "\nSigue a " + twitter.showUser(i).getFriendsCount() + " usuarios" + 
                          "\nTiene " + twitter.showUser(i).getFollowersCount() + " seguidores\n");
                      }  
                   }
                }
                while(friendsIDs.hasNext());

                frame.setTitle("Información sobre seguidores de " + twitter.showUser(twitter.getId()).getName() + " - BISmart");
                panelCargando.setVisible(false);
                tweetsPanel.setVisible(true);
                tweetsPanel.setFocusable(true);
                tweetsPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

So, finally I see the "tweetsPanel" panel with the textArea and the "panelCargando" in the front. In that code that I put here, I changed it and added "panelCargando.setVisible(false)", but this way I can't see it at all.

Can anyone help me with this? If it's not clear please let me know! Thank you all!

**EDIT**

Now the code is this one, but I keep having problems with the same. Even if I do "layout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelCargando")", the panel doesn't show. I added this:

```
layout = new CardLayout(0,0);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
frame.getContentPane().add(splashPanel, "splashPanel");
frame.getContentPane().add(newTweetPanel, "newTweetPanel");
frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, "mainPanel");
frame.getContentPane().add(tweetsPanel, "tweetsPanel");
frame.getContentPane().add(optionsPanel,"optionsPanel");
frame.getContentPane().add(panelCargando, "panelCargando");
```

And the actionPerformed looks like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            layout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelCargando");
            long lCursor = -1;
            IDs friendsIDs;
            try
            {
                friendsIDs = twitter.getFriendsIDs(twitter.getId(), lCursor);
                System.out.println(twitter.showUser(twitter.getId()).getName());
                do
                {

                  for (long i : friendsIDs.getIDs())
                  {
                      if(textArea.getText().isEmpty())
                      {
                          textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "ID de usuario: " + i +
                          "\nNombre de usuario: @" + twitter.showUser(i).getScreenName() + 
                          "\nNombre: " + twitter.showUser(i).getName() +
                          "\nDescripción: " + twitter.showUser(i).getDescription() +
                          "\nImagen de perfil: " + twitter.showUser(i).getProfileImageURLHttps() +
                          "\nSigue a " + twitter.showUser(i).getFriendsCount() + " usuarios" + 
                          "\nTiene " + twitter.showUser(i).getFollowersCount() + " seguidores\n");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\nID de usuario: " + i +
                          "\nNombre de usuario: @" + twitter.showUser(i).getScreenName() + 
                          "\nNombre: " + twitter.showUser(i).getName() +
                          "\nDescripción: " + twitter.showUser(i).getDescription() +
                          "\nImagen de perfil: " + twitter.showUser(i).getProfileImageURLHttps() +
                          "\nSigue a " + twitter.showUser(i).getFriendsCount() + " usuarios" + 
                          "\nTiene " + twitter.showUser(i).getFollowersCount() + " seguidores\n");
                      }  
                   }
                }
                while(friendsIDs.hasNext());

                frame.setTitle("Información sobre seguidores de " + twitter.showUser(twitter.getId()).getName() + " - BISmart");
                layout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "tweetsPanel");
            }
```

Comment: You are saying you using `CardLayout`, but then you manually setting `visible` properly to `true/false`!!!! Why is that so? Moreover, where exactly you have written the `Card Swapping` part inside the `actionPerformed(...)` of the `JButton`, if you using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). I am not been able to see any `CardLayout` methods like `first/last/previous/next/show` anywhere in this part of the snippet.

Comment: I have edited the code, thanks man, but still not working, look at it.

Comment: A small runnable example, will be highly appreciated, to know the cause of the problem. If possible :-)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Sorry for being out. I made it work as you said, using CardLayout and show() method. Thank you all!